# oracle 11, update join

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I have a SQL-Statement like this:

```
UPDATE tbl
SET old_ht = new_ht,
    old_ttc = new_ttc
from table1 tbl 
join table2 temp ON trim(temp.val_code) = trim(tbl.val_code) 
                 AND trim(temp.tv_code) = trim(tbl.tv_code)
INNER JOIN table3 tbl3 ON  trim(tbl3.oma_CODE) =trim(temp.oma_CODE) 
                       AND trim(tbl3.men_CODE) =trim(temp.men_CODE) 
                       AND  trim(tbl3.gov_CODE) =trim(gov.BRD_CODE)
                       and tbl3.fld_id = tbl.fld_id  ;
```

But it seems that Oracle does not support this syntax.

I also tried this:

```
UPDATE ( select tbl.cost_ht as old_ht, temp.cost_ht as new_ht,tbl.cost_ttc as old_ttc
                ,  temp.cost_ttc as new_ttc
         from table1 tbl 
         join table2 temp ON trim(temp.val_code) = trim(tbl.val_code) 
                 AND trim(temp.tv_code) = trim(tbl.tv_code)
         INNER JOIN table3 tbl3 ON  trim(tbl3.oma_CODE) =trim(temp.oma_CODE) 
                       AND trim(tbl3.men_CODE) =trim(temp.men_CODE) 
                       AND  trim(tbl3.gov_CODE) =trim(gov.BRD_CODE)
                       and tbl3.fld_id = tbl.fld_id )
SET old_ht = new_ht, old_ttc = new_ttc
```

But I get this error:

Error report:

> SQL Error:
>   ORA-01779: cannot modify a column which maps to a non key-preserved table 01779. 00000 -  "cannot modify a column which maps to a non key-preserved table"
>   *Cause:    An attempt was made to insert or update columns of a join view which
>   map to a non-key-preserved table.
>   *Action:   Modify the underlying base tables directly.

Comment: Maybe provide an example of tables and explain what are you trying to do.

Comment: Your dbms is complaining, because it doesn't consider it guaranteed to only see each tbl record once in your select result. So you cannot update this view, but must update the table instead.

Answer (score 0):

As simple as that.. Provide more confidence to your engine by this index.

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IDX1
    ON TABLE1 ( VAL_CODE,TV_CODE );

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IDX2
    ON TABLE2 ( VAL_CODE,TV_CODE, OMA_CODE ,MEN_CODE );

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IDX3
    ON TABLE3 ( OMA_CODE ,MEN_CODE, GOV_CODE  );
```

Then try your query, which should run fine

```
UPDATE
      (SELECT
            TBL.COST_HT AS OLD_HT,
            TEMP.COST_HT AS NEW_HT,
            TBL.COST_TTC AS OLD_TTC,
            TEMP.COST_TTC AS NEW_TTC
       FROM
            TABLE1 TBL
            JOIN TABLE2 TEMP
                ON TRIM ( TEMP.VAL_CODE ) = TRIM ( TBL.VAL_CODE )
                   AND TRIM ( TEMP.TV_CODE ) = TRIM ( TBL.TV_CODE )
            INNER JOIN TABLE3 TBL3
                ON      TRIM ( TBL3.OMA_CODE ) = TRIM ( TEMP.OMA_CODE )
                   AND TRIM ( TBL3.MEN_CODE ) = TRIM ( TEMP.MEN_CODE )
                   AND TRIM ( TBL3.GOV_CODE ) = TRIM ( GOV.BRD_CODE )
                   AND TBL3.FLD_ID = TBL.FLD_ID)
SET
      OLD_HT        = NEW_HT,
      OLD_TTC     = NEW_TTC;
```

Comment: But On TABLE1,  I can have many records with the same( VAL_CODE,TV_CODE). I have to add "FLD_ID" for getting uniques records.

Comment: and for TABLE2 , I have to use VAL_CODE,OMA_CODE, MEN_CODE ,GOV_CODE

Comment: Yes also on Table3. Updating answer