# Oracle update query NULL error

Tags: sql, oracle, join, sql-update

I have 3 tables:

```
Table1
-------
ID
Field1
Field2


Table2
_______
ID
Name


Table2_OLD
____________
ID
Name
```

I need to update ID in table 2 to the ID from Table2 where Table2.Name = Table2_OLD.Name

IDs in Table2 and Table2_OLD are different, only Names are to be used to get the correct ID:

```
SELECT Table2.ID 
FROM Table2 
  INNER JOIN Table2_OLD ON Table2.Name=Table2_OLD.Name
```

I wrote the following update statement:

```
UPDATE Table1 SET Table1.ID=(SELECT DISTINCT t2.ID
                             FROM Table2 t2
                               INNER JOIN Table2_OLD t3 
                                       ON t2.Name=t3.Name 
                                      AND t2.ID=Table1.ID)
```

but it gives me an error

> cannot update Table1.ID to null`

I tried using

```
UPDATE Table1 SET Table1.ID = (SELECT DISTINCT t2.ID
                               FROM Table2 t2
                                 INNER JOIN Table2_OLD t3 
                                         ON t2.Name=t3.Name 
                                        AND t2.ID=Table1.ID 
                                        AND NOT t2.ID is null)
```

but got the same error.

Can anyone help?

Comment: I think you want a `WHERE` clause with that update statement, not a subquery.

Comment: I cannot access any values from subquery from the update statement

Comment: There is no `join` keyword in the syntax of [`update`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/UPDATE.html).

Comment: If you need to restrict the rows to be updated, then add a `where` clause to the `update`.

Answer (score 1):

Haven't tested it but a correlated update in Oracle should work:

```
UPDATE table1 t1
SET id = (SELECT DISTINCT t2.id
          FROM table2 t2
          JOIN table2_old t3 ON
            t2.name = t3.name
          WHERE t3.id = t1.id
          )
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM table2 t2
  WHERE t3.id = t1.id
)
```

Comment: I changed your query slightly, as table1 and table2 are not connected in any way:  UPDATE table1 t1
SET t1.id = (SELECT t2.id
          FROM table2 t2
          JOIN table2_old t3 ON
            t2.name = t3.name
          WHERE t3.id = t1.id
          )
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM table2_old t3
  WHERE t3.id = t1.id
)
but now I am getting an error that subquery returns multiple results (ID is not unique to the table)

Comment: How are table1 and table2 not connected? See your condition: `AND t2.ID=Table1.ID`. You need that condition, otherwise you would get the error you got...

Comment: Table1 and Table2 have no direct connection. Table1.ID= Table2_OLD.ID and Table2_OLD.Name=Table2.Name. And I want to update Table1.ID with Table2.ID

Comment: I've updated the answer. Is it OK now?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to `JOIN` Update, You can try this.

```
UPDATE (
    SELECT t2.ID t2ID,t1.ID t1ID
    FROM Table1 t1
    INNER JOIN Table2_OLD t2Old ON t1.ID= t2Old.ID
    INNER JOIN Table2 t2 ON t2.Name=t2Old.Name 
    WHERE t2.ID is NOT null
) 
SET t1ID = t2ID
```

Comment: actually Table1 and Table2 have no direct connection. Table1.ID= Table2_OLD.ID and Table2_OLD.Name=Table2.Name. And I want to uodate Table1.ID with Table2.ID

Comment: @CodingDuchess OK,I edit my answer,If that didn't hit your expect you can provide some sample data and expect result, let the question clear :)

Comment: Now I am getting an error `cannot modify a column which maps to a non key-preserved table`

Comment: Right, the view needs to be key-preserved. You must be missing a unique constraint on the parent of one of the joins. https://stackoverflow.com/q/20143115/230471